# Does db.run_in_transaction return anything?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I'm mimicking a transaction example I found in the [Taggable Mixin](http://code.google.com/p/taggable-mixin/), but it's not behaving in the same manner.

```
def txn():
    // statements omitted for brevity
    blog_index.put()
    new_post = Post(key_name=new_post_key_name, parent=blog_index,
                           index = new_index, title = new_title,
                           body = new_body)
    new_post.put()
    return new_post

def new_post(cls, new_title=None, new_body=None, new_tags=[]):
    new_post = db.run_in_transaction(txn)

    new_post.tags = new_tags
    new_post.put()
```

In this example, the `new_post` from `txn` is returned through `db.run_in_transaction`, then something can be done with it. But I am getting:

```
TypeError: object is not callable
```

This leads me to believe the function `run_in_transaction` is getting assigned to the `new_post` variable, not the actual `new_post` returned from `txn`.

**Can `db.run_in_transaction` return anything, like the values from the callable function?**

Comment: run_in_transaction returns the value that your transaction function returns.  (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#run_in_transaction)  You need to include more code for us to help you spot the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`run_in_transaction` returns whatever the called function returned. You need to include the compelte stacktrace and the original code for us to help.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. This was a mistake on my part. One of the statements in the "abridged" section included a call to 3rd-party library that also used a transaction. Adjusting for that, I inadvertently added a param to txn and called it incorrectly.